# Customize ggplot so geom_abline layer appears only for a specific range along the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here I'm creating a linear model and putting the coefficients for that model in a graph.

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(intercept = coefficients(model)[1], slope = coefficients(model)[2])
```

[image]

How could I make it so this line only extends between a custom range along the x-axis? If I wanted the line to only appear between the ranges of wt = 2 and wt = 4, for instance? Geom_abline I think just runs forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predict()` y values for your desired range limits, then use those values with `geom_line()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

trendline <- data.frame(wt = c(2, 4)) 
trendline$mpg <- predict(model, newdata =
trendline)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = trendline)
```

[image]